# Amazon hosting cant install .Ca-bundle

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

Iv been using chrome as my main broswer for a while but have deciced to start using firefox to my surprise to see that my domain has an ssl issue.

I narrowed down the problem to my Amazon ec2 not having the .ca-bundle installed from when i set up my ssl.

thankfully i still have the email where i got my domain info and i have the .ca-bundle

How ever im not sure where to upload this to.
iv looked around on amazons faq page and its very confusing.

If anyone has some advice. let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to retrace my steps.
In my case i had to access my directory

```
/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/
```

place the file www_example_com.ca-bundle in this directory
then goto

```
/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami
```

Sudo nano bitnami.conf
And add the following line underneath my already set ssl and keys

```
SSLCertificateChainFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/www_example_com.ca-bundle"
```

I hope this helps anyone in the future.